# Storing/uncoupling behaviour

Tags: c++, design-patterns, scripting

I am making use of the Type Object pattern (as described on gameprogrammingpatterns.com), which was just what I needed to avoid redundancy of *data* and make it easier to reduce hardcoding. In short I have something like this:

```
class Action
{
   // ...
   ActionType& Type;
}
```

where `ActionType` is the type object that holds static data for this particular type of `Action`. There will be several instances of `Action`, so the memory expenditure is reduced considerably (as compared to storing the type data in each `Action` instance). It also makes it possible to load action type parameters from a script, but it doesn't work with *behavior*.

I'm finding it necessary to derive from `Action` to support different behavior, which kind of defeats the purpose. I could of course use some sort of callable object to parametrize behavior in the `ActionType` object, but that would still necessitate hardcoding.

How does one go about something like this? Scripting? If that is the way, is it possible to precompile a script for better performance in the release?

**Update:** To clarify, each `Action` has an `OnUpdate()` function that I want to customize for every type of action, without involving inheritance and hardcoding.

Comment: Looks like acandidate for boost::any

Comment: Thanks, but how would that help? I thought boost::any was a kind of placeholder for any kind of variable.

Comment: I suggest you show some more code, because I didn't understand exactly what is the question.

Comment: Added a little update at the bottom.